# How to pass value from ts file to scss file in same component in angular 2+?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular2-template

This is my component

```
export class myComponent implements onInit {

private outageCount;

ngOnInit(){

    ....subscribe((data) => {
    this.outageCount = Object.keys(data).length;

})
}
```

I need to pass the outageCount to my css before `CONTENT`

```
:host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {
    &:before{
        //content:"4";
        content:attr(outageCount);
        background: #941313;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        left: 22px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 13px;
        width: 13px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        color: white;
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 13px;
    }
```

How can i pass the outageCount value from my component to css :before `content`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not use ngClass or ngStyle for setting attributes based on typescript values

Comment: @IzzoObella I have to change it in :host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {
    &:before{}. How can i use ngStyle for that?

Comment: may be `/deep/` helps you.  prepend `/deep/` before class name

Answer (score 7):

I'm passing this as attribute in my html like below

```
 [attr.outage-count]="outageCount"
```

I css, i updated like this

```
   :host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {
        &:before{
            content: attr(outage-count);
            ......
        }
    }
```

This works for me!! Thanks for all those who tried helping me!

Comment: can you please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106757/how-to-pass-value-from-typescript-code-to-css-in-angular-6/65106941?noredirect=1#comment115104111_65106941

Comment: I want to change the cursor value using the same approach. but I got error that "attr()" is only possible to be used with content. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

try using :

> document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--contentvalue', this.outageCount);

**css**

```
:root {
    --contentvalue: 4;
}

:host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {
    &:before{
        //content:"4";
        content:attr(--contentvalue);
        background: #941313;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        left: 22px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 13px;
        width: 13px;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        color: white;
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 13px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the this. I found someother way. let me update!

Comment: @RamyaS can you let us know the other way it worked for you?