# How to set background images in angular + ionic app inside home.page.scss?

Tags: angular, sass, ionic4

I am angular plus ionic 4 framework, i am apply background image through .scss file but it is not working correctly. here is html and scss code.[image]

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380916/how-to-pass-value-from-ts-file-to-scss-file-in-same-component-in-angular-2/49381608#49381608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Ionic 4 which uses so-called Shadow DOM technique, You can access some elements only with variables so for changing background

```
ion-content {
 --ion-background: url('../asssets/...') !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine I think all you need to do is remove `page-home{}` 
[image]

SCSS cant reference the selector of the component the scss is contained in, in ionic 4

Answer (score 0):

**SASS Variables**

IONIC 4 is using sass variables now , so you can try using :

```
ion-content{
    --background: #fff url('assets/abc.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```