# How to pass value from typescript code to css in Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I know I've to use `ngClass` or `ngStyle` but I'm not able to figure out how to pass that value. Here is my code.

**strip.component.ts**

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-strip',
    templateUrl: './strip.component.html'
})
export class StripComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    @Input() widthValue: any; // getting this from parent component

    staticKpi:{...}=[][]
}
```

**strip.component.html**

```
<ng-container>
    <div *ngFor="let row of staticKpi">
        <div class="rows" *ngFor="let item of row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>{{widthValue}}</h2> <!-- this is printing correct value-->
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

I've to decide width of *rows* class dynamically in scss something like this:

**strip.component.css**

```
.rows {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/widthValue); // <----- here
    text-align: left !important;
    background: red;
}
```

I could have used `col-{{widthValue}}` in HTML but no, I've been told that it has to be from the width property from css.
Please help me. I'm not sure how to use ngClass here.

Comment: Use `ngStyle` to set the width dynamically.

Comment: you can use in the .html: `[style.width]="(100/widthValue)+'%'"` or `[ngClass]="'col-'+widthValue"`

Comment: @Eliseo, this didn't work. elements just crashed into each other as if the width was zero. :-(

Comment: you can use any expresion, like, e.g. `[style.width]="widthValue?(100/widthValue)+'%':'1%'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `class`

```
<div [class]="'col-'+ widthValue"></div>
```

OR

Use `style.width`

```
<div [style.width]="(widthValue/12)*100 + '%'"></div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sa6xzj)

Comment: What does the `widthValue` hold? Is there any other error?

Comment: No there's no other error related to this. `widthValue` is just a numeric value. It is actually the grid size.

Comment: By grid size, you mean the bootstrap grid column size out of 12?

Comment: Yes you can say that. Actually there is a varibale you can see `stripKpi`. It is a 2D array. I've to display this array in matrix form. So 6 elements mean 2 rows and 3 columns. In this case `3` will be my `widthValue`. this logic has already been written. So now i just want width to be calculated accordingly.

Comment: i think this will do. I'm accepting this answer. thanks a lot for your time :-)